# Use a string as Window Height in XAML

Tags: wpf, string, xaml, height, width

I made a window with some parameters:

```
<Window x:Class="MsgBox"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MsgBox" Height="300" Width="500" Topmost="True" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" WindowStyle="None" Loaded="MsgBox_Loaded">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I want to change the height and width to these calculated strings. It gets the users screenwidth and height and divide it by four.

```
Public ReadOnly Property PrimaryScreenWidth As Double
    Get
        Return System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth
    End Get
End Property

Public ReadOnly Property PrimaryScreenHeight As Double
    Get
        Return System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight
    End Get
End Property


Private MsgBoxWidth As String = PrimaryScreenWidth \ 4
Private MsgBoxHeight As String = PrimaryScreenHeight \ 4
```

How to set it to my window?

```
    Height="{x:static MsgBoxHeight }" Width="{x:static MsgBoxWidth }" ??
```

Comment: Why would you define it as a string? WPF handles integers/floats in XAML as well.

Comment: And then how to use it? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do this, why don't you simply

```
Me.Height = MsgBoxHeight
Me.Width = MsgBoxWidth
```

when you calculated the properties?

Answer (score 0):

The syntax you're showing and presumably want, with the curly braces:

```
Height="{x:static MsgBoxHeight }" Width="{x:static MsgBoxWidth }"
```

is called Markup Extension syntax, it allows using a markup extension class to set a property value.  Here's how you'd do it. First step, create the markup extenssion class:

```
Public Class MsgBoxHeight
    Inherits System.Windows.Markup.MarkupExtension

    Public Sub New()
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Function ProvideValue(serviceProvider As IServiceProvider) As Object
        Return System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight / 4
    End Function
End Class
```

Next you'll add a `xmlns:local="clr-namespace=YourNamespace"` to the `<Windows>`, then you'll be able to use it like this: `Height="{local:MsgBoxHeight}"`.

The complete XAML for the Window would look like this:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication6"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="{local:MsgBoxHeight}" Width="525">
    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

### Note

Using the Markup Extension means you're doing it *from code*. You are introducing a nice application-specific extension to XAML, but you need *code* for it to work. If you only need to do this for one Window it makes more sense to simply set the `Height` and `Width` of the window from the code-behind and not bother with the Markup Extension.